# mt5.initialize fails with error code: (-10003, "IPC initialize failed, Pipe server didn't answer in 60 sec")

Tags: metatrader4, mql5, forex, metatrader5

When I call [MetaTrader5.initialize](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5initialize_py) passing in the exe file path and the login credentials, it is opening the Metatrader terminal with the last logged in account ignoring the one passed in the initialize method, then it errors out with error code: (-10003, "IPC initialize failed, Pipe server didn't answer in 60 sec"). The account is a MT5 account.

I have also tried the other flavor of calling initialize with just the exe path argument and doing a login call separately. The initialize method called in this way also fails with the same error.

I'm hopelessly stuck and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the python module can talk to mt4 accounts. In the same way the terminal/account type pairs are mutually exclusive. I have occasionally made this mistake with the terminal programs, but not with the python code...

Comment: I made a typo when I posted my question. I'm actually trying to connect to a MT5 account, corrected the typo.